# Brown spots on avocado tree leaves

Tags: leaves, diseases, indoors, fungus, avocado

I transplanted my 7 years old avocado tree two months ago and since then it's condition continually worsened. First, the leaves lost turgor for a few weeks and I thought that this was over. Fortunately, recently leaves started to regain the turgor but then brown spots of various sizes appeared on all of them. Moreover, there are also small brown dots on some of them and the leaf buds are withered. It is winter here but the heater is off and the temperature in the house is about 21°C. What are these spots? Can I do anything do help my plant?

Below, I attach some photos of my avocado.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to inline your images.

Comment: Those look like necrotic spots on the leaves from over fertilising.  What did you transplant it into?

Comment: I haven't fertilized it since I transplanted it into universal soil with perlite.

Comment: So it must be another reason. Maybe fungi?

Comment: What is universal soil?

Comment: Good quality potting soil